# Laravel 5 Route Failing to work

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.4

I'm upgrading from Laravel 4.2 to 5.4 and I'm not understanding why the converted route is not working for the URL: http://{domain}/admin/page/provider.home

Here are the pertinent details as it was structured in Laravel 4.2:

```
Route::filter('provider_admin', function()
{   
    // Specific logic to potentially redirect to a specific page
}

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin/page'), function()
{
    Route::get('/{page}', array( 'before' => 'provider_admin', 'as' => 'admin_page', 'uses' => 'Frozennode\Administrator\AdminController@page' ));
    Route::get('/{page}/{id}', array( 'before' => 'provider_admin', 'as' => 'admin_page', 'uses' => 'Frozennode\Administrator\AdminController@page' ));
});
```

In Laravel 5.4, filters have been moved to middleware, so I have the following:

ProviderAdmin.php

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ProviderAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        // Specific logic to potentially redirect to a specific page
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Inside web.php

```
// Route::middleware('provider_admin')->prefix('admin/page')->group(function () 
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin/page', 'middleware' => 'provider_admin'], function () {
{
    Route::get('{page}', ['as' => 'admin_page', 'uses' => '\Frozennode\Administrator\AdminController@page' ]);
    Route::get('{page}/{id}', ['as' => 'admin_page', 'uses' => '\Frozennode\Administrator\AdminController@page' ]);
    die('ROUTE NOT FOUND');
});
```

kernel.php

```
'provider_admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\ProviderAdmin::class,
```

The request enters the group, but unlike in Laravel 4.2, it doesn't enter the middleware, but ends with 'ROUTE NOT FOUND'. What other fundamental issue am I missing that was apparently introduced in Laravel 5 Routing?

Comment: `Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin/page'), function()` 

means your url is like `localhost/admin/page/page_name` and  `localhost/admin/page/page_name/1`

I am not exactly sure what you doing here 

`http://{domain}/admin/page/provider.home`

Comment: Exactly Rodrane, and provider.home is the page_name.

Answer (score 0):

***Try this***

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin/page', 'middleware' => 'provider_admin'], function () {
     Route::get('{page}','\Frozennode\Administrator\AdminController@page')->name('admin_page');
     Route::get('{page}/{id}','\Frozennode\Administrator\AdminController@page' )->name('admin_page_by_id');
     die('ROUTE NOT FOUND');
});
```

Comment: Still doesn't go into the middleware handler, thanks for trying. I think it might have to do with the Frozennode/Administrator package I'm using, although I obviously can't figure out why.